# Feed social for multiple accounts

Tags: plugin, twitter, social, feed

Someone can suggest about a social feed plugin for EE3/4 that allow to have feeds for multiple accounts?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [Smart Social Feed](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/smart-social-feed). This module is available in EE2, EE3 and EE4.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm not sure if I can have multiple accounts with this one ... like for example for twitter:

Twitter account 1 >> feeds.
Twitter account 2 >> feeds.
Twitter account n >> feeds.

Comment: Sure you can have multiple account feeds and you can fetch it individually. I know because I am the developer of that module. :) . You can review documentation before purchase, It will help you to make right decision http://www.zealousweb.com/expressionengine/smart-social-feed/

Comment: Can you please confirm that I can have one page which outputs feeds from a lot of different accounts, e.g. on this one page I will have 3 twitter feeds, 2 facebook feeds and 4 youtube feeds. And you can display them all in one page, amongst each other, by date order? So I may have one tweet from account 1, then 2 Facebook posts from account 2, then an instagram from account 4? Thanks @mufi

Comment: Sure you can do this with our module. All you need to do is to add valid KEY and SECRET of accounts to backend and on front end orderby data by date in DESC or ASC mode. (Our module is made on this purpose actually :) )

Comment: Hi. Can you confirm that this module is work for you? Or if you have any query or issue regarding this, I can help you on that..